# Knockout - manage html blocks conditionally

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, markup

I have multiple blocks of markup that I need to change order of display and show/hide based on different conditions. I thought of using knockout templates but cant figure out how to get it working properly. I have wrapped each block with script tags and added IDs but I need a little bit of help in creating the viewmodel. Im a little lost on how to render the markup.

Can someone guide me in creating a basic viewmodel for this scenario?]

**Update**

I have messed around with it using the provided answers given below as reference. The way its setup right now makes it easy to add scenarios and I think this would work for my purpose but I'd like to know if this can be improved.

Markup:

```
    <div id="parent-container">
        <!-- ko foreach: items -->
        <div data-bind="template: {name: templateID}"></div>
        <!-- <div data-bind="template: {name: $root.template}"></div> -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>

    <script type="text/html" id="tmp1">
        <p>
            Section 1
        </p>
    </script>

    <script type="text/html" id="tmp2">
        <p>
            Section 2
        </p>
    </script>

    <script type="text/html" id="tmp3">
        <p>
            Section 3
        </p>
    </script>
```

JS:

```
var container = document.getElementById('parent-container');

var viewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.items = ko.observableArray();
        self.renderScenario = function(data){
            // self.items.push({'template':'df'});
            var templates = data.templates;
            for(var i = 0; i<templates.length; i++) {
        self.items.push({'templateID' : templates[i]});
      }
        };
};

var scenarios = [
    {'id:': 'scenario1', 'templates': ['tmp1', 'tmp2'] },
    {'id:': 'scenario2', 'templates': ['tmp1', 'tmp2', 'tmp3']}
];

var vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm, container);

vm.renderScenario(scenarios[1]);
```

Comment: Could you post some sample code? You may need to combine the template bindings with some conditional bindings. You can also make the value of the template binding an observable, and the template will then load the markup in the script tag with the corresponding ID. In any case, I'm not sure what the best strategy is without an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @EvanWise thats the thing - I haven't done this sort of thing before and I have no specific Knockout coding done for this. You are right about using an observable for the template but then again I need to just tell the viewmodel a specific condition and then the viewmodel should render all related markup blocks for that condition.

Answer (score 0):

If each block is just raw html, you can use the html binding. The fiddle link has a more robust example with buttons that move the blocks around.

http://jsfiddle.net/6hrvytkk/

```
<!-- ko foreach: items -->
  <div data-bind="visible: visible">
      <span data-bind='html: html'></span><br/><br/>
  </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

js

```
var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.items = ko.observableArray();
    self.load = function(data){
        self.items([]);
        for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
            self.items.push(data[i]);
        }
    };
};

var vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
var htmlBlobs =
[
    {'html': "Sup", 'visible': ko.observable(true)},
    {'html': "Hey", 'visible': ko.observable(true)},
    {'html': "Doood", 'visible': ko.observable(true)},
    {'html': "<ul><li>+ numba 1</li><li>+ numba 2</li><li>+ numba 3</li></ul>", 'visible': ko.observable(true)},
    {'html': "Yup", 'visible': ko.observable(true)},
    {'html': "Sure thing", 'visible': ko.observable(true)},
    {'html': "Can I help you?", 'visible': ko.observable(true)},
];
vm.load(htmlBlobs);
```

Comment: Thanks. only issue is that markup is a little complex and uses php syntax as well. So I need to have the markup in the html file.

Comment: @user3312508 There are a lot of ways to drop your markup into the viewmodel. You can plop the markup into divs like this http://jsfiddle.net/autavem6/. You can also put the markup into individual HTML files and use a jquery.load('test.html') into your viewmodel.

Comment: I'v messed around with it following your example. I think it can work for my purpose but I'd like to know if that can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example using templates. Without more details, I can't be sure that this solves your problem, but hopefully it will help you understand the template binding and conditional bindings.

```js
var vm = {
  navItems: ko.observableArray([{
    name: "first-template",
    display: "First Template"
  }, {
    name: "second-template",
    display: "Second Template"
  }, {
    name: "third-template",
    display: "Third Template"
  }]),
  currTemplate: ko.observable("first-template"),
  selectTemplate: function(template) {
    vm.currTemplate(template.name);
  },
  extrasVisible: ko.observable(false),
  toggleExtras: function() {
    vm.extrasVisible(!vm.extrasVisible());
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.main {
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.sidebar {
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  background: grey;
  text-align: center;
}
.content {
  height: 400px;
  padding: 30px;
  float: right;
  width: 66.7%;
}
.sidebar ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.sidebar li {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5%;
  background: light-grey;
}
.extra {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/html" id="first-template">
  First template content.
  <span class="extra" data-bind="if: $root.extrasVisible">
    Here is some extra content, shown optionally.
  </span>
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="second-template">
  Second template content.
  <span class="extra" data-bind="if: $root.extrasVisible">
    Here is some extra content, shown optionally.
  </span>
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="third-template">
  Third template content.
  <span class="extra" data-bind="if: $root.extrasVisible">
    Here is some extra content, shown optionally.
  </span>
</script>

<div class="main">
  <nav class="sidebar">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: navItems">
      <li data-bind="click: $root.selectTemplate">
        <a href="" data-bind="text: display"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: toggleExtras">
      Toggle Extras
    </button>
  </nav>
  <div class="content" data-bind="template: currTemplate">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for working on it. I'v played it with and came up with a solution but I'd like to improve it if possible(Code updated in OP). I think using `navItems` as an array is a good idea and i would try to use it. Do you think i can improve my code or see any issues?

Comment: It looks good to me. The template binding is powerful, even if it can be a bit confusing at first. Also, note that you, strictly speaking, don't have to use script tags for your templates. If you support HTML5, you can use the template tag, which has the advantage of proper HTML syntax highlighting.